# React router renders the invalid component then renders valid component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Whenever I go the the path ("/") even if I am logged in, Signup component is loaded once for few second then Dashboard is shown same happens with redirecting how to solve it.

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => {
        return loggedIn ? <Dashboard /> : <Signup />;
    }}
/>

<Route
    exact
    path="/resetPassword"
    render={() => {
        return loggedIn ? (
            <Redirect to="/" />
        ) : (
            <ResetPassword/>
        );
    }}
/>
```

and I'm setting the `login` like this:

```
const cookieCheck = () => {
  const mt = Cookies.get("rt");
  if (mt === "" || mt === undefined) {
    if (loggedIn) {
      setLogin(false);
    }
  } else {
    if (!loggedIn) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    }
  }
};
```

My complete code is as follows

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect, lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import Dashboard from './Components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import LoadingPage from './Components/LoadingPage/main';
import ForgotPassword from './Components/ForgotPassword/Fp';
import Signup from './Components/Signup/Signup';
import Login from './Components/Login/Login';
import PageNotFound from './Components/404/Page.js';
import Activation from './Components/Activation/Activation';
import ResetPassword from './Components/ResetPassword/Reset';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const App = () => {
    const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

    const checkStatus = function () {
        const mt = Cookies.get('t');
        if (mt === '' || mt === undefined) {
            setLogin(false);
        } else {
            setLogin(true);
            // return true;
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            cookieCheck();
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    });

    const cookieCheck = async () => {
        const mt = await Cookies.get('rt');
        if (mt === '' || mt === undefined) {
            if (login) {
                setLogin(false);
            }
        } else {
            if (!login) {
                setLogin(true);
            }
        }
    };

    console.log(login);
    return (
        <Router>
            <Fragment>
                <Paper elevation={0}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            path="/forgotpassword"
                            exact
                            component={ForgotPassword}
                        />
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/login"
                            render={() => {
                                return login ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Login />;
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/signup"
                            render={() => {
                                if (login) {
                                    return <Redirect to="/" />;
                                } else {
                                    return <Signup />;
                                }
                            }}
                        />

                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/"
                                render={() => {
                                    return login ? (
                                        <Dashboard />
                                    ) : (
                                        <LoadingPage />
                                    );
                                }}
                            />


                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/resetPassword/:code/:uid"
                            render={() => {
                                return login ? (
                                    <Redirect to="/" />
                                ) : (
                                    ResetPassword
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path="/activation/:code/:uid"
                            component={Activation}
                        />
                        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                </Paper>
            </Fragment>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Typically you use a "loading" or "pending" state to conditionally render something else other than your route component while the authentication is checked/processing. Can you provide a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so we've more context around updates to `loggedIn`?

Comment: @DrewReese can you please elaborate...

Comment: show how `loggedIn` state is being set?

Comment: Sure, the component with router mounts and issues effect to check authentication and while that asynchronous action is processed you set a "pending" state. When the authentication is determined, update state to set the `loggedIn` value and set "pending" back to false. Or if using redux, use a similar pattern. Basically any time you are checking the authentication don't render your route UI.

Comment: @TaghiKhavari 
I am setting it using cookies
`const cookieCheck = () => {
  const mt = Cookies.get('rt');
  if (mt === '' || mt === undefined) {
   if (loggedIn) {
    setLogin(false);
   }
  } else {
   if (!loggedIn) {
    setLoggedIn(true);
   }
  }
 };`

Comment: @DrewReese Ok I got it now, but how do I solve it? will it work if I create a function where I check the state and then render it

Comment: I mean edit the code you post and put it there :)

Comment: Please just edit your question to include the full code example.

Comment: @TanayMakwana function `cookies.get()` is an `asynchronous` function which returns a `promise` so you need to use `promise.then` or `async await ` keyword to handle it

Comment: @TaghiKhavari Its not working... I tried it

Comment: @TaghiKhavari thanks for the code but its not working

Comment: Continually saying "it's not working," isn't very helpful. What isn't working? Are there any error messages? What debugging are you doing? Please elaborate.

Comment: @DrewReese whenever the page is refreshed  the state is updated based on cookies. and even if the user is logged in the sign up page displays for few seconds and then dashboard is getting displayed.

Comment: "Shows the signup page for a ... seconds and then dashboard..." made me look at the effect and interval, you don't immediately check the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is you don't immediately check the cookie status when the component mounts. This coupled with `login` initial state `false` will render any `login ? true : false` false branch component until the first cookie check that returns valid authentication.

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

const checkStatus = function () {
    const mt = Cookies.get('t');
    if (mt === '' || mt === undefined) {
        setLogin(false);
    } else {
        setLogin(true);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        checkStatus(); // <-- not called for 1000ms
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
});
```

## Solution

Need to also immediately invoke the cookie check function. I suggest also starting with a non-true/false state value so you know when the initial check is complete.

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState(null);

const checkStatus = function () {
    const mt = Cookies.get('t');
    if (mt === '' || mt === undefined) {
        setLogin(false);
    } else {
        setLogin(true);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        checkStatus();
    }, 1000);
    checkStatus(); // <-- also invoke first render
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Check for `login === null` and return null (*or any pending/loading UI really*), otherwise return the regular ternary.

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  render={() => {
    if (login === null) return null;
    return login ? (
      <Dashboard />
    ) : (
      <LoadingPage />
    );
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need try something like this to add `loading` state to your component:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect, lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import Dashboard from "./Components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import LoadingPage from "./Components/LoadingPage/main";
import ForgotPassword from "./Components/ForgotPassword/Fp";
import Signup from "./Components/Signup/Signup";
import Login from "./Components/Login/Login";
import PageNotFound from "./Components/404/Page.js";
import Activation from "./Components/Activation/Activation";
import ResetPassword from "./Components/ResetPassword/Reset";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const App = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const checkStatus = function () {
    const mt = Cookies.get("t");
    if (mt === "" || mt === undefined) {
      setLogin(false);
    } else {
      setLogin(true);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      checkStatus();
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  console.log(login);
  const isLoginComponent = login ? <Dashboard /> : <LoadingPage />;
  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        <Paper elevation={0}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/forgotpassword" exact component={ForgotPassword} />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/login"
              render={() => {
                return login ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <Login />;
              }}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/signup"
              render={() => {
                if (login) {
                  return <Redirect to="/" />;
                } else {
                  return <Signup />;
                }
              }}
            />

            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => {
                return loading ? <div>loading</div> : isLoginComponent;
              }}
            />

            <Route
              exact
              path="/resetPassword/:code/:uid"
              render={() => {
                return login ? <Redirect to="/" /> : ResetPassword;
              }}
            />
            <Route exact path="/activation/:code/:uid" component={Activation} />
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Paper>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Read more about how `cookies` work here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/get

Comment: thanks @TaghiKhavari , but its not working

Comment: @TanayMakwana are you sure that you're using the `cookies` correctly? put all of your code in the question

Comment: code is really big stackoverflow is showing error while putting

Comment: try to put it section by section or create a code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/